# Reading the base of the stack frame in c++ on windows

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, 64-bit, inline

I trying to port the [vaiven](https://github.com/MichaelRFairhurst/vaiven) virtual machine code to windows for learning purposes.

I compiled and tested the code on Linux. Most of the c++ code compiles fine with visual studio 2019 community edition.
There is one function that i don't know how to port it to windows. My guess is that this class allows to get the base of the stack frame.

```
class Stack {
      uint64_t* rbp();
};
uint64_t* __attribute__ ((noinline)) vaiven::Stack::rbp() {
       asm("mov (%rbp), %rax");
}
```

After googling about assembler using Intel notations I deduced that the equivalent code would be:

```
__declspec(noinline) uint64_t*  vaiven::Stack::rbp() {
    __asm 
    {
        mov  rax, DWORD PTR [rbp];
    }
}
```

But I don't have any background in assembler coding. So I have two questions :

1. Is this translation to intel assembler correct ?
2. The Visual Studio community edition does not support inline
   assembler for x64 targets. But it supports [Intrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh977022(v=vs.140)) . Can we get the base of the stack frame in C/C++ code without writing assembler code in an external file
   ?

Thanks

Comment: The code might not even use `rbp` as stack frame pointer. The code won't work on linux either if you use optimized build. I haven't looked what the VM uses the value for, but it could be replaced by taking the address of a local variable or similar. Of course layout of locals is also at the discretion of the compiler.

Comment: I compiled with g++ -O3 on linux and it work very well. Mau be the "__attribute__ ((noinline))" tells the compiler to do not optimize it.  This project code is the fastest VM i tested. It's faster than luajit. I thought also like you to return the address of this but it does not work.

Comment: That probably means it is only used for informational purpose. Enabling `-O3` turns off using `rbp` for frame pointer so the code simply can not do anything useful. Or maybe you haven't tested functionality that would actually need this `rbp` value.

Comment: You are right. This is supposed to be called by the garbage collector but it was never called when executing running some benchmark scripts.

Comment: Just guessing here, but the garbage collector presumably just wants to use it as a boundary for the memory search. As such, declaring a local variable and returning its address should work.

Comment: Great. Many thanks. You helped me to understand the use of this function.

Comment: As Jester points out, there's no reason to expect `RBP` to even hold a valid pointer if you compile with optimization enabled.  Unless you also use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or something to disable the standard optimization.  Use [`__builtin_frame_address(0)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) in GNU C++, or take the address of a local to get a stack address which should work anywhere.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Yes the code is compiled on linux with ``-O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer``.